# Animating background color of CommandBar in UWP crashes

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

I've been working at animating the background color and opacity of `CommandBar` over an image for it to become more opaque when the mouse cursor is moved.

The XAML code I'm using for the animation is as follows:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="topbagroundfadeinout">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="topcmdbar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Black" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Black" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="Transparent" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

And the C# event handler looks like this:

```
private void raiseopacity(object s, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (topcmdbarfadeinout.GetCurrentState()!=ClockState.Active)
    {              
        topcmdbarfadeinout.Begin();
        topbagroundfadeinout.Begin();
    }
}
```

If I include only the fade in/out of the opacity, everything works fine. However, as soon as I uncomment the XAML code for the background color animation, the program compiles but execution crashes with a weird error

> Failed to create a 'Windows.Foundation.Double' from the text 'Transparent'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]

Anyone knows what's wrong? Or anyone has a better way to do this?

Comment: Obviously don't use a DoubleAnimation for a Color. Use a ColorAnimation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoubleAnimation` is meant for `double` data type. Instead in this case you are animating `Windows.UI.Color`, which has a dedicated `ColorAnimation` and its `EasingColorKeyFrame` elements.

Also, you will probably need to modify the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to `(CommandBar.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`, as it is a complex property.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="topbagroundfadeinout">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="topcmdbar" 
     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CommandBar.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Black" />
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Black" />
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="Transparent" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Also note, that `Transparent` color is actually a white color with 0 opacity. This can prove to be a problem, as the animation will essentially fade from white to black instead of from invisible black to black. I have written more about this in [on my blog](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/04/when-a-single-transparent-color-is-simply-not-enough/).

In your case, you may be better off specifying the transparent black instead of `Transparent` manually:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="topbagroundfadeinout">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="topcmdbar" 
     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CommandBar.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00000000" />
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Black" />
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Black" />
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="#00000000" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Although the difference might not be noticeable in all situations, you may try both solutions to see which better fits with your intended use.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Sure thing :-), happy coding!

Comment: `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"` is sufficient.

Comment: I thought so, but it hasn't worked for me. Maybe a typo